# SQL query looking up number of acquaintances

Tags: sql

I have a table named Membership with the columns Name and ClubName. These basically show which people belong to which club. The tables People and Clubs have a many-to-many relationship. What I want to find is the person who knows the most other people on the basis of them being in the same club. So it's for every single person in Membership, count all the different people who are in the same club as them and return the one with the most people. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
select
  m.name,
  count (distinct m2.name)
from
  Membership m join 
  Membership m2 on m.clubName = m2.clubName 
group
  by m.name 
order by
  count (distinct m2.name) desc
```